# Schedule a theme change using cron

Tags: 10.10, themes, crontab

I am trying to figure out how to automatically switch to the Equinox Evolution Dawn, Light, Dusk, and midnight theme at the appropriate time of day (ie; at 6 a.m. it would switch from midnight to dawn, at 8 or 9 it would switch to light, 7 p.m. would switch to dusk and 10 p.m. switch to midnight)

I am trying to do this using cron, with the following crontab:

0 6 * * * gconftool-2 --type=string --set /apps/metacity/general/theme 'equinox-evolution-dawn'

0 8 * * * gconftool-2 --type=string --set /apps/metacity/general/theme 'equinox-evolution-light'

0 19 * * * gconftool-2 --type=string --set /apps/metacity/general/theme 'equinox-evolution-dusk'

0 22 * * * gconftool-2 --type=string --set /apps/metacity/general/theme 'equinox-evolution-midnight'

This is not working. I am using ubuntu 10.10 with Compiz as window manager

Comment: Not a precise answer to your question, but you might see [Gnome theme which changes depending on the time of day](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/11/gnome-theme-which-changes-automatically.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? No part of the theme changes?

Comment: That's correct. No part of the theme changes in any way that I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this script? (adapted from [New Wave -Chronos](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/New+Wave+-+Chronos?content=116182))

```
#!/bin/bash
# Autor: Narf SS 2009
# Site: http://proyectobs.blogspot.com/
#
# Este script cambia el archivo de configuración del tema metacity "New Wave Chronos"
#y actualiza el tema.
#Para su funcionamiento (sin modificación) debe de ser añadido a la ejecución en el inicio, 
#y el tema debe de estar instaldo en la carpeta ".theme" del home del usuario.
#Y por supuesto seleccionado en la apariencia del escritorio y este mismo script añadido a las aplicacioens de inicio.

while [ true ]
do
    hora=`date +%H`

    case "$hora" in
    06|07)          # Amanecer
        gconftool-2 --type=string --set /apps/metacity/general/theme 'equinox-evolution-dawn' ;;
    08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18)   # Medio dia
        gconftool-2 --type=string --set /apps/metacity/general/theme 'equinox-evolution-light' ;;
    19|20|21)               # Atardecer
        gconftool-2 --type=string --set /apps/metacity/general/theme 'equinox-evolution-dust' ;;
    22|23|24|00|01|02|03|04|05) # Madrugada
        gconftool-2 --type=string --set /apps/metacity/general/theme 'equinox-evolution-midnight' ;;
    esac


    sleep 1h
done
```

Comment: That successfully changes the metacity theme, but not the GTK or icon themes...where would I find the commands for changing those, and how would I insert them into this script?

Comment: Just add something like: && gconftool-2 --type string --set /desktop/gnome/interface/icon_theme 'theme_name' after every gconftool-2 --type=string --set /apps/metacity/general/theme 'equinox-evolution-dawn'

Comment: It now works correctly, had to do a few tweaks to the script because I had some of the theme names off and, in the case of the Light one, the metacity theme was actually Equinox Evoluution Rounded

Comment: -----Nice!-----